# make css gallery resposive if it is with fixed size

Tags: html, css

Hello I am using the following gallery code for a slide show, my question is how to make this gallery responsive right now the size is fixed but I would like to be able to shrink it with the viewport metatag. here is the code of the gallery and the css

**html code:**

```
<div class="splash_gall">
            <div class="box_gall">
                <div class="hide_photo"></div>
                <div id="viewport">
                    <div class="slider_gall">
                        <ul class="items">
                         <li><img src="img/gall_pic_5.jpg" alt></li>
                         <li><img src="img/gall_pic_6.jpg" alt></li>
                         <li><img src="img/gall_pic_8.jpg" alt></li>
                         <li><img src="img/gall_pic_12.jpg" alt></li>
                         <li><img src="img/gall_pic_7.jpg" alt></li>
                         <li><img src="img/gall_pic_13.jpg" alt></li>
                         <li><img src="img/gall_pic_10.jpg" alt></li>
                         <li><img src="img/gall_pic_9.jpg" alt></li>
                        </ul>             
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.splash_gall {
  position: relative;
  position: absolute;
  top: 198px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -510px;
}
.box_gall {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 563px;
}
.hide_photo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1021px;
  height: 564px;
  background: url('../img/photo_over.png') 0 0 repeat;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
}
#viewport {
  width: 1020px;
  height: 563px;
  cursor: move;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider_gall {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1530px;
  height: 579px;
}
.items {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried media queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css media queries for this, like explained on: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/